# How to open an image file and display in ImageView with Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I developing an image processing application where the user needs to click on some button to open the internal storage file system to browse for image files, I need to display the image selected by the user inside the `ImageView` object on my layout. I have the code below but when I select on a sample image then the image is not displayed in my `ImageView` object, it shows nothing. I have started the file browsing activity with this code....

```
            //show the file manager with extensions
            Intent image_intent= new Intent(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);
            image_intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            //set the type for image files
            image_intent.SetType("image/*");
            StartActivityForResult(image_intent, 899);
```

and then I override the `OnActivityResult()` method so that I could get my image data from the Intent data passed back when this event occurs but my code seems to have some bit of a problem. Here is the code that is supposed to create a Bitmap from the file and then display it in the ImageView

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                if (requestCode == 899)
                {
                    //display the image in the ImageView
                    Android.Net.Uri myuri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new File(data.Data.Path));
                    File myfile = new File(myuri.ToString());
                    //define a new set of BitmapOptions
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.OutWidth = imageView.Width;
                    options.OutHeight = imageView.Height;
                    Bitmap mymap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(myfile.AbsolutePath, options);
                    //display it in the imageview
                    imageView.SetImageBitmap(mymap);
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Loading the image into the ImageView", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            }
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong, Thank You for your help.

Comment: have you stepped through this code to verify it is executing as expected?  Have you checked for any exceptions or errors?

Comment: `imageView.SetImageUri(data.Data);`. Thats all. You are abusing the File class for your uri.

Comment: @ blackapps Lemme try the changes you suggested in your comment, Thanjs for your effort

Comment: @Jason , yeah I have an image inside the draw able directory and it displays but when I browse an image file and tap on it it does not show up in the image view

Comment: `it displays but when I browse an image file and tap on it it does not show up in the image view`  Do you mean the image in your device storage?

Comment: @Jessie Zhang -MSFT the code comment by blackapps worked , Thanks for the concern anyways

Comment: Congrats, and thanks for your support for xamarin.